# Calculating Azimuth, Elevation and skew angles when pointing toward sattelite

Tags: polarization, satellites

I have some phased array antenna which is installed on aircraft and pointing itself (azimuth, elevation, skew polarization angles) by plane angles (lat, long, roll, pitch, heading) and satellite location.

The antenna is providing its data (azimuth, elevation, skew angles) in plane body and i'd like to verify that it behaves as required. I've found out how to calculate the azimuth and elevation angles, but don't know how to calculate the skew angles.

I'm willing to do a double verification: in plane axis and in earth axis. I really understand that there shall be some Euler transformation (and inverse transformation).

P.S. skew angle is deviation angle between two linear polarizations.
The polarization is linear rotating

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @hyportnex, how to do the calculation of skew angle

Comment: You should edit your post with that question together with a definition of what a *skew polarization angle* is, I have never heard that term. Do you mean polarization error between two linear polarizations? What is the polarization of the antenna array, is it circular or linearly polarized?

Comment: @hyportnex, I've added to the post

Comment: OK, it is clear now, but the reason for circular polarization is that you need not worry about the mismatch angle between the polarizations as you must when the polarization is linear. Do you see why? There maybe a mismatch angle between the *axes* of the transmit and receive antennas but for that it is not enough to know the location of the satellite (elevation, azimuth) but also its antenna pointing axis vector relative to its platform, the same needed for your own antenna. Then just take the scalar product of the two axis vectors, for the received power the cosine of the angle is needed.

Comment: @hyportnex, just verified the spec - polarization is linear rotating

Comment: you have to set up an earth based fixed coordinate system in which you track the satellite and then you have to calculate the relative tilt (misalignment) of the two antenna axes from the scalar product of the two vectors, see chapter 5 in Roddy: "Satellite Communications". What satellite system is this?